# Powershell - Search 2 values into .xml file with regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I hope your well in this particular situation.

Request description: 
To make my life easier into my day to day, I try to write à powershell script where the goal is to find the each "Name" tables where "reserved" size > 1G

Below an example of output i want to get based on xml file sample below

Output

- Table name: tr_stat_history
- Table size: 3,829623 GB
- Table name: appctrl_exefile
- Table size: 1,58016 GB

xml file sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
<record>
<field value="tr_stat_history" name="Name"/>
<field value="1024936 " name="Rows"/>
<field value="3829623 KB" name="reserved"/>
<field value="38120 KB" name="Data"/>
<field value="120 KB" name="index_size"/>
<field value="56 KB" name="Unused"/>
</record>
<record>
<field value="appctrl_exefile" name="Name"/>
<field value="2149679 " name="Rows"/>
<field value="1580160 KB" name="reserved"/>
<field value="120376 KB" name="Data"/>
<field value="37336 KB" name="index_size"/>
<field value="304 KB" name="Unused"/>
</record>
<record>
<field value="appctrl_pdffile" name="Name"/>
<field value="2149 " name="Rows"/>
<field value="1580 KB" name="reserved"/>
<field value="1203 KB" name="Data"/>
<field value="3733 KB" name="index_size"/>
<field value="508 KB" name="Unused"/>
</record>
</data>
```

What could be the best way to get my goal?

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach you can try out. I've added comments to explain the logic.

```
# Create XML object to load data into
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

# Load in XML file
$xml.Load("input.xml")

# Iterate each child node underneath the data tag
foreach ($node in $xml.data.ChildNodes)
{
    # Get name and reserved fields
    $name = $node.field | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Name"}
    $reserved = $node.field | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "reserved"}

    # Split on whitespace and take the digit
    # Do KB conversion to bytes by multiplying by 1024
    $kb = [long]$reserved.Value.Split(' ')[0] * 1024

    # Check if bigger than 1GB or 1073741824 bytes
    # Output table name and size if this is true
    if ($kb -gt 1GB)
    {
        Write-Output "Table name: $($name.Value)"
        Write-Output "Table size: $($kb / 1GB) GB"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Table name: tr_stat_history
Table size: 3.65221309661865 GB
Table name: appctrl_exefile
Table size: 1.5069580078125 GB
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regex, you might want to approach this using Powershell's xml parsing capabilities.

I'm not up-to-speed with how to best use xml so following has undoubtly room for improvement but you can get the gist of it using following example.

```
(
    [xml]@'
    <root>
        <record>
            <field value="tr_stat_history" name="Name"/>
            <field value="1024936 " name="Rows"/>
            <field value="3829623 KB" name="reserved"/>
            <field value="38120 KB" name="Data"/>
            <field value="120 KB" name="index_size"/>
            <field value="56 KB" name="Unused"/>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field value="appctrl_exefile" name="Name"/>
            <field value="2149679 " name="Rows"/>
            <field value="1580160 KB" name="reserved"/>
            <field value="120376 KB" name="Data"/>
            <field value="37336 KB" name="index_size"/>
            <field value="304 KB" name="Unused"/>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field value="appctrl_pdffile" name="Name"/>
            <field value="2149 " name="Rows"/>
            <field value="1580 KB" name="reserved"/>
            <field value="1203 KB" name="Data"/>
            <field value="3733 KB" name="index_size"/>
            <field value="508 KB" name="Unused"/>
        </record>
    </root>
'@
).root.record | % {if (([int]($_.Field[2].Value -split ' ')[0])*1024 -gt 1GB) {$_.Field[0].Value}}
```

where

- I've added a `root` element to have valid xml
- Cast the string a an `[xml]` type
- Loop over all `record` elements with `%`
- Test the `reserved` field. As the value contains a string, I've split it on a space, taken the first element of the resulting array, cast it as an integer and multiply with 1024. After that, it's a simple compare with `1GB`
- Only if the `reserved` field is > 1GB, the `name` field gets output

Comment: Hello Lieven, thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, I cannot change the xml content :(
My only way should be to use something similar as Select-String -Path .\flo.xml -Pattern 'reserved' etc ...

Comment: @LEFBE -  From your latest edit, it looks like you just need to change the `root` in my example to `data` and you are good to go.

Comment: @Lievent could you please provide me an example of usage of this code?

Comment: @LEFBE - I have pasted your example into a `$env:TEMP\test.xml` file. After that, it's just `([xml](gc $env:TEMP\test.xml)).data.record | % {if (([int]($_.Field[2].Value -split ' ')[0])*1000 -gt 1GB) {$_.Field[0].Value}}`

Comment: Hello Lieven, 

Thanks for your help: the following code display table where size is over 1GB ^^ I'm so happy.
Do you thinks it's possible to add size information, I've only the table name?

Code used 
$ResultXMLfile = Read-Host "Path to result.xml"
([xml](gc $ResultXMLfile)).data.record | % {if (([int]($_.Field[2].Value -split ' ')[0])*1000 -gt 1GB) {$_.Field[0].Value}}

Answer (score 1):

Both solution are amazing ! 
Thanks for your help !

I use the following:

```
# Create XML object to load data into
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

$ResultXMLfile = Read-Host "Path to result.xml"

# Load in XML file
$xml.Load($ResultXMLfile)

# Iterate each child node underneath the data tag
foreach ($node in $xml.data.ChildNodes)
{
    # Get name and reserved fields
    $name = $node.field | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Name"}
    $reserved = $node.field | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "reserved"}

    # Split on whitespace and take the digit
    # Do KB conversion to bytes by multiplying by 1024
    $kb = [long]$reserved.Value.Split(' ')[0] * 1024

    # Check if bigger than 1GB or 1073741824 bytes
    # Output table name and size if this is true
    if ($kb -gt 1GB)
    {
        Write-Output "Table name: $($name.Value)"
        Write-Output "Table size: $($kb / 1GB) GB"
    }
}
```

In my case, my xml contains 35k lines, so in few second I got my answer.

```
Path to result.xml : C:\Users\Usernames\Desktop\Download\all_result\all_result\result.xml
Table name: appctrl_exefile_hst
Table size: 2.74079895019531 GB
Table name: nl_storage_items
Table size: 2.76924133300781 GB
```